# Electron App - How do i open link in browser?

Tags: electron

im trying to open a link in a new browser window using a Electron App.

```
const test = () => {
  const shell = window.require('electron').shell;
  shell.openExternal("https://google.com");
}
```

When i do this, i get error `"window.require is not a function"`

I have ofcourse made my research on this, and found several "fixes" but none has worked for me. I have edited my `webpack.config.js` to this:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
      externals: {
        './cptable': 'var cptable'
      },
      resolve: {
        fallback: {
          'fs': false,
          'crypto': false,
          'path': false,
        }
      }
    },
  }
```

I have also made sure `nodeIntegration` enabled like so:

````
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true
        },
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        resizable: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })
    ```

still no success. any idea?
````

Answer (score 1):

renderer.js - from your renderer send request.

```
const response = await window.electronAPI.openLinkPlease()
```

preload.js - you have this middleware where your request will receive to send to electron.

```
process.once("loaded", () => {
  contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
      openLinkPlease: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('openLinkPlease'),
  })
});
```

electron.js - here you will get your request to open and electron will open this url in your default browser.
First add at the very beginning `const {shell} = require("electron");`  to add shell capabilities and than after

```
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
});
```

add

```
ipcMain.handle('openLinkPlease', () => {
    shell.openExternal("https://google.com");
})
```

This is the screen how it works from my application
[image: This is the screen how it works from my application]